# why my video doesnt play in html5?

Tags: javascript, html, video, mp4, ogg

I am trying to play a video with html5. Its not working in any browser.

I create buttons for play/pause etc.
I use functions to enable the button functionalities.

I use a [w3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp) but my video is not working.

I just see a black screen.

I get below error i firebug when i click on buttons.

> TypeError: myVideo is null

My code is below. Why my video doesnt work?

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br> 
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="mov_bbb.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<script> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
  myVideo.play(); 
else 
  myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig()
{ 
myVideo.width=560; 
} 

function makeSmall()
{ 
myVideo.width=320; 
} 

function makeNormal()
{ 
myVideo.width=420; 
} 
</script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do the files exist under the same directory/path as the site requested?

Comment: try to add 'autoplay' here: <video id="video1" width="420" autoplay>. If the video starts there's something wrong in the code, otherwise the problem is that the source video doesn't exists in the same folder of the html page.

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi I added autoplay but still i only see a black screen. The videos are actually under "videos" folder and my source is "videos/mov_bbb.mp4"

Comment: so in your root folder you have the page with this code and in the "videos" folder the mp4/ogg. In the code you've specified <source src="videos/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4"> right? If so, try to clear your cache

Comment: @AlbertoFecchi Yes, that's right. I will try clearing my cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is fine see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/florestan06/EV4er/1/) - if I plug the sample URL from videojs it works fine.

May I suggest you try reading this [article](http://diveintohtml5.info/video.html) to get started with HTML5 video rather than W3schools.

You either have a file format issue with your video file or a server config issue (probably with your mime types but everything is explained in the above link).

If you want to know more about the exact reason for your error code you can try the code at the end of this [section](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/video.html#video).

HTML5 video can be tricky in the beginning but you will get to it :)

JSfiddle code:

```
<div style="text-align:center"> 
  <button onclick="playPause()">Play/Pause</button> 
  <button onclick="makeBig()">Big</button>
  <button onclick="makeSmall()">Small</button>
  <button onclick="makeNormal()">Normal</button>
  <br /> 
  <video id="video1" width="420">
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
    <source src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/v/oceans.webm" type="video/webm"></source>
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
  </video>
</div> 

<script type="text/javascript"> 
var myVideo=document.getElementById("video1"); 

function playPause()
{ 
if (myVideo.paused) 
myVideo.play(); 
else 
 myVideo.pause(); 
} 

function makeBig()
{ 
myVideo.width=560; 
} 

function makeSmall()
{ 
myVideo.width=320; 
} 

function makeNormal()
{ 
myVideo.width=420; 
} 
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you sure that your source path is correct?

Another thing to check is your .htaccess.

Add the following to your .htaccess file on your server:

```
AddType video/ogg .ogv .ogg
AddType video/webm .webm
AddType video/mp4 .mp4
```

Comment: how can edit the .htaccess file? I am using Dreamweaver cs3 and cpanel but this file seems to be empty

Comment: It depends on which webhosting provider you are working on. Where the .htaccess is located, it should be on the manual on your webhosting provider. Just add the lines to the .htacess

Comment: i added these lines in the .htaccess file but nothing happen. note that this file has nothing else inside